# How to match Stata percentile calculation in Excel formula?

Tags: excel, stata

Stata uses the method of quantile calculation called R-2 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile), whereas Excel uses R-7 with percentile.inc function. My goal is to find a correct formula in Excel that would give results identical to ones in Stata with the R-2 method.

For now, I can see that percentile.inc matches Stata results only for odd and discrete samples (I am dealing with discrete samples). However, the issue occurs with even [samples shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qblMN.png)

Conceptually, using percentile.inc in Excel does not seem to be correct since it is an R-7 method, even though it matches with the R-2 method for odd and discrete samples.

My question is what is the simplest formula that would be correct to use in Excel to match Stata percentile results?

Comment: To match you would need to actually recreate the base formula do the regression your self.  there is no easy way.  You will need to do it long hand.

Comment: Just for interest, what happens with the zeroth percentile in Stata? It looks to me as though R-2 would go wrong and try to address ' x sub zero' ? Otherwise, it doesn't look too bad to implement because the subscripts are always integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a fairly literal translation of R-2 into Excel for N=4 would look like this (assuming sorted data):

```
=(INDEX(A$2:A$5,CEILING(C2*4,1))+INDEX(A$2:A$5,FLOOR(C2*4+1,1)))/2
```

[image]

It does indeed go wrong if you try and put in a quantile of zero so that would have to be a special case as would a quantile of 1. I assume Stata gives the lowest and highest values in the set in these two cases?

A more dynamic formula with all the checking would look like this:

```
=IFS(OR(C2<0,C2>1),"Out of range",C2=0,A$2,C2=1,INDEX(A:A,COUNT(A:A)+1),TRUE,(INDEX(A$2:INDEX(A:A,COUNT(A:A)+1),CEILING(C2*COUNT(A:A),1))+INDEX(A$2:INDEX(A:A,COUNT(A:A)+1),FLOOR(C2*COUNT(A:A)+1,1)))/2)
```

although you could make it shorter using the Let construct in Microsoft 365.

It would probably be nice to implement this as function in VBA which would sort the data as well as returning the quantile value or of course you could do the sort in a Microsoft 365 formula as well:

```
=LET(N,COUNT(A:A),sortedRange,SORT(A$2:INDEX(A:A,N+1)),IFS(OR(C2<0,C2>1),"Out of range",C2=0,INDEX(sortedRange,1),C2=1,INDEX(sortedRange,N),TRUE,(INDEX(sortedRange,CEILING(C2*N,1))+INDEX(sortedRange,FLOOR(C2*N+1,1)))/2))
```

Comment: So the original formula assumed there were exactly four values in the dataset, so it only applied to the even case where N=4. The subsequent formulas count the number of data points - I have tested them on the four groups of data from your test sample and they seem to agree with Stata. Sorry if that wasn't clear.

Comment: Why is that the R-2 calculation of the 50th percentile in Stata always matches Excel's R-7 calculation?

Comment: Intuitively, I would expect the 50th percentile or median to be 'in the middle', i.e. on the middle value (odd) or half-way between the two middle values (even). The Wikipedia entry https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile supports this notion 'R‑3 and R‑4 are not symmetric in that they do not give h = (N + 1) / 2 when p = 1/2' or in other words all the others _are_ symmetric and do give h = (N + 1) / 2 when p = 1/2.